# Searching for the folder in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When you open a folder on Windows with content inside, you can easily find the file you need by simple typing it's name.

For example, for folder `System32` you can just type `sys` and it will focus on the folder which stars with `sys`.

However, when you type a wrong letter by mistake, it takes some time till windows timeouts the wait for the user input.

For example, I want to focus on folder `System32`, but by mistake the first letter I type is `d` instead of `s`.

Therefore I cannot use quick-focus anymore and I have to look for it manually.

This quick-focus helps to navigate if you have lots of files in one place.

Question: Is there a shortcut to cancel the old or start the new focus-search? So that if I type a wrong key, I can start from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `ESC` to ignore your last pressed key.

Answer (score -1):

with a file/folder selected in a directory you can only search by the first letter - progressing through the results for the chosen letter by pressing the same letter again.

using the search function within the explorer window itself you simply delete your entry.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser and thanks for your answer. You can actually type multiple letters and have explorer more finely select an item. For example typing 'driv' to select the drivers folder.